# Why is this jQuery not working?

Tags: jquery, variables

```
$(function () {


   var sr = 'section.row';
   var fot = 'figure.one_third';
   var pA = 'div.portfolio ul li a'; 

   var item = ('sr fot pA');

   $item.addClass('blue');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G8yJj/13/ <<

Comment: why the extra quotes on the `var $item` line? (instead of just `var $item = $(pA);`)

Comment: yeah...even if you want to put quotes before and after they should probably match...  i.e.: '' + pA + '' or "" + pA + ""

Comment: Edited the post, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: `var item = $(sr + ' ' + fot + ' ' + pA);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the line needs to be:

```
var item = $(pA);
item.addClass('blue');
```

or in your updated question:

```
var item = $(sr + ' ' + fot + ' ' + pA);
```

if that's what you want.

Comment: cheers mate, I gave u the green tick because you answered it first. Although I appreciate the help from all of you.

Comment: Hi @動靜能量, it's common practice to prefix jQuery object variables with a $. So `$item` instead of `item`.

Answer (score 1):

*There's no need for any extra quotes.*

**Just use** `var $item = $(pA);`

Answer (score 1):

sr and fot are not getting evaluated as variables, they are just part of the string.

You need

```
$(sr + "," + fot + "," + pA)
```

Comment: As a side note, I think your variable names are very nondescript. Ask yourself if another developer would have any idea what those variable names mean. Or if you would have any idea what they mean 6 months down the road. Readability -> Maintainability my friend

Answer (score 0):

As [cambraca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368864/cambraca) said in a comment, no quotes.

```
$(function () {

   var pA = 'div.portfolio ul li a'; 

   var $item = $(pA);

   $item.addClass('blue');

});
```

You do write

```
   var $item = $("div.portfolio ul li a");
```

But thats only because you need to have a way to mark the selector `div.portfolio ul li a` as a non-javascript query. If you explicitly make a String with those contents, then quoting it would read like this.

```
   var $item = $('"' . '"div.portfolio ul li a"' .'"');
```

And, that doesn't make sense.